# if else statement and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm trying to shorten my code using if else instead of just a whole bunch of if statements like I normally do, however I made a mistake somewhere and don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Ideally this snippet of code should have the "postQuantity" field have the values of "Select Fence Height", "Select Fence Style", "Select Picket Size", and then the result of the inputs after they are put through a JQuery equation. If anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you! Here is a JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gv0029/8PR9C/ and here is the code:

HTML:

```
<form>
<fieldset id="fence">
    <div name="inputFence" class="inputFence">
        <legend><strong>Fence Description</strong>
        </legend>
        <label>Footage:
            <input name="footage_1" class="footage" />
        </label>
        <select name="fenceHeight_1" class="fenceHeight">
            <option value="select">Select Fence Height</option>
            <option value="6" id="fH6">6 Ft.</option>
            <option value="8" id="fH8">8 Ft.</option>
        </select>
        <select name="fenceStyle_1" class="fenceStyle">
            <option value="select">Style</option>
            <option value="bnb" id="bnb">Board on Board</option>
            <option value="sbs" id="sbs">Side By Side</option>
        </select>
        <select name="picketSize_1" class="picketSize">
            <option value="select">Picket Size</option>
            <option value="1x3.5x6" id="1x4">1 x 3.5 x 6</option>
            <option value="1x4x6" id="1x4">1 x 4 x 6</option>
            <option value="1x5x6" id="1x4">1 x 5 x 6</option>
            <option value="1x5.5x6" id="1x4">1 x 5.5 x 6</option>
            <option value="1x6x6" id="1x4">1 x 6 x 6</option>
        </select>
        <legend><strong>Post Type</strong>
        </legend>
        <label>Picket Quantity
            <input name="picketQuantity_1" class="picketQuantity" />
        </label>
    </div>
</fieldset>

</form>
```

JS:

```
//Quantity for Pickets          
$(document.body).on('keypress keydown keyup change', '[class^="footage"],[class^="fenceHeight"], [class^="picketSize"],[class^="fenceStyle"], [class^="picketQuantity"]', function() {

            var parts = $(this).attr('name').split("_");
                fenceNumber = parts[1],

                footage = parseFloat($(":input[name='footage_" + fenceNumber + "'" + ']').val(), 10),
                fenceHeight = $(":input[name='fenceHeight_" + fenceNumber + "'" + ']').find('option:selected').val(),
                fenceStyle = $(":input[name='fenceStyle" + fenceNumber + "'" + ']').find('option:selected').val(),
                picketSize = $(":input[name='picketSize" + fenceNumber + "'" + ']').find('option:selected').val(),              
                picketQuantity = $(":input[name='picketQuantity_" + fenceNumber + "'" + ']'),
                total = '';

        if (!isNaN(Number(fenceHeight))) {  
            if (fenceStyle == 'sbs') {
                 if (picketSize == '1x3.5x6' || picketSize == "1x4x6" || picketSize == "1x5x6") {
                    total = (((Math.ceil((footage * 12) / 3.5)) * 1.05));
                 } else if (picketSize == '1x5.5x6' || picketSize == "1x6x6") {
                    total = (((Math.ceil((footage * 12) / 5.5)) * 1.05));
                 } else {
                    total = "Select Picket Size";
                 }
                    picketQuantity.val(total);
            } else if (fenceStyle == 'bnb') {
                 if (picketSize == '1x3.5x6' || picketSize == "1x4x6" || picketSize == "1x5x6") {
                    total = (((Math.ceil((footage * 12) / 8.5)) * 3) * 1.05);
                 } else if (picketSize == '1x5.5x6' || picketSize == "1x6x6") {
                    total = (((Math.ceil((footage * 12) / 10.5)) * 3) * 1.05);
                 } else {
                    total = "Select Picket Size";
                 }
                    picketQuantity.val(total);
            } else {
                picketQuantity.val("Select Fence Style");
            }   
        } else {
            picketQuantity.val("Select Fence Height");
        }

});
```

Comment: What indication do you have that something is wrong?  When you step through this in a debugger, at what point does the logic not behave as you expect?

Comment: What are the consequences of "doing it wrong?" In other words, we need to know what does/doesn't happen compared to what's supposed to happen.

Comment: Lol sorry, it get to where the output is "Select Fence Style" and that is it. No matter what style I pick and even if I pick the picket style as well it just keeps saying "Select Fence Style".

Comment: THe idea is that as they select each of the components of the equation that they would be prompted to select the value of the next component until JS has everything it needs to output the "picketQuantity".

Comment: **EDIT** - Above I referred to the "postQuantity" when I meant to refer to the "picketQuantity" but I can't edit the question (I suppose since people have already started responding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just missed adding the "_" to a few of your attribute queries...

```
//Quantity for Pickets          
$(document.body).on('keypress keydown keyup change', '[class^="footage"],[class^="fenceHeight"], [class^="picketSize"],[class^="fenceStyle"], [class^="picketQuantity"]', function() {

            var parts = $(this).attr('name').split("_");
                fenceNumber = parts[1],

                footage = parseFloat($(":input[name='footage_" + fenceNumber + "'" + ']').val(), 10),
                fenceHeight = $(":input[name='fenceHeight_" + fenceNumber + "'" + ']').find('option:selected').val(),
                fenceStyle = $(":input[name='fenceStyle_" + fenceNumber + "'" + ']').find('option:selected').val(),
                picketSize = $(":input[name='picketSize_" + fenceNumber + "'" + ']').find('option:selected').val(),              
                picketQuantity = $(":input[name='picketQuantity_" + fenceNumber + "'" + ']'),
                total = '';

        if (!isNaN(Number(fenceHeight))) {  
            if (fenceStyle == 'sbs') {
                 if (picketSize == '1x3.5x6' || picketSize == "1x4x6" || picketSize == "1x5x6") {
                    total = (((Math.ceil((footage * 12) / 3.5)) * 1.05));
                 } else if (picketSize == '1x5.5x6' || picketSize == "1x6x6") {
                    total = (((Math.ceil((footage * 12) / 5.5)) * 1.05));
                 } else {
                    total = "Select Picket Size";
                 }
                    picketQuantity.val(total);
            } else if (fenceStyle == 'bnb') {
                 if (picketSize == '1x3.5x6' || picketSize == "1x4x6" || picketSize == "1x5x6") {
                    total = (((Math.ceil((footage * 12) / 8.5)) * 3) * 1.05);
                 } else if (picketSize == '1x5.5x6' || picketSize == "1x6x6") {
                    total = (((Math.ceil((footage * 12) / 10.5)) * 3) * 1.05);
                 } else {
                    total = "Select Picket Size";
                 }
                    picketQuantity.val(total);
            } else {
                picketQuantity.val("Select Fence Style");
            }   
        } else {
            picketQuantity.val("Select Fence Height");
        }

});
```

Comment: *facepalm* I was sure I was doing something with the if else statements because I rarely use them. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can do this. Maybe try something like this-

```
fenceCalculations = {
    "sbs": function(args)
    {
        // do stuff
        // return size
    },
    "bnb": function(args)
    {
        // do stuff
        // return size
    }
}

var size = fenceCalculations[fenceStyle](args);
```